# How powerful are weak complexity classes with powerful oracles?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

I am interested in complexity classes of the form $A^{B}$, where $A$ and $B$ are complexity classes such that $A \subsetneq \mathsf{P}$ and $\mathsf{NP} \subsetneq B$ are (believed to be) true.

First, is this a well-defined question? Are there any known results about the structure of such classes?

Second, is there an explicit problem in one of $\mathsf{NC}^{\mathsf{NP}}$, $\mathsf{NL}^{\mathsf{NP}}$, $\mathsf{FNC}^{\# \mathsf{P} }$, or $\mathsf{FNL}^{\# \mathsf{P}}$ and which is not in $\mathsf{P}$ under some assumption? After some research, I have not been able to find such a problem.

Comment: You can start from Klaus Aehlig, Stephen Cook, Phuong Nguyen, "[Relativizing Small Complexity Classes and their Theories](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.5508)", 2012.

Comment: For your second question, $(\mathsf{AC}^0)^\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{P}$.

Comment: Furthermore, Kaveh's previous comment holds for any reasonable uniformity condition. $\hspace{.59 in}$

Comment: A more interesting example (though still not answering your first question): $\mathsf{L}^{\mathsf{NP}} = \Theta^P_1 := \mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}[\log n]}$.

Comment: I don't understand your second question; isn't $\mathsf{SAT}$ an explicit problem in $\mathsf{NC}^\mathsf{NP}$ which is not in $\mathsf{P}$?